# Link to new page in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to apply links to next page in WordPress? I want to go to page.php from index.php.

href= i used this code.

Comment: page.php is common page for all pages works like template for all pages in wordpress except custom pages

Answer (score 1):

basically it's `<a href="page.php">Click to go to page.php</a>`

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/HhPC9/

(of course the link doesn't work because there is no such a page there)

**this is a general answer, it could be that wordpress have it's own pages system and page.php is actually all the pages "page" and with the parameter you navigate through those pages.